Accessing node_modules in composite action on GitHub
How do I access the node_modules directory from a composite action in the calling job?
Given a GitHub actions workflow file:
name: main-job

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

defaults:
  run:
    working-directory: ./backend

jobs:
  lint:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - run: ls -a

      - uses: ./.github/actions/services-install-dependencies
        with:
          node-version: 20
          GPR_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GPR_TOKEN }}

      - run: ls -a

and a composite actions file
name: composite-action

inputs:
  node-version:
    required: true
  GPR_TOKEN:
    required: true

runs:
  using: composite
  steps:
    - name: Setup Node
      uses: actions/setup-node@v4
      with:
        node-version: ${{ inputs.node-version }}

    - name: Install dependencies
      shell: bash
      run: npm ci

    - run: ls -a
      shell: bash

I would expect the last ls -a command to print node_modules, but it doesn't.
Expected
ls -a (node modules not existing, called from job)
ls -a (node modules existing, called from composite)
ls -a (node modules existing, called from job)

Actual
ls -a (node modules not existing, called from job)
ls -a (node modules existing, called from composite)
ls -a (node modules not existing, called from job) <---- !!

The reason I ask about this is because I want to do the node setup and the npm package installation in a composite action so that I can just run npm run build or npm run build in different jobs without duplicating so much code in every job.

Try pwd in- and outside of the action to see what path you're at. I thought the working directory for both would be the repo root directory, but maybe not?

I have edited my post now since I excluded the working-directory config (I did not think it mattered). The issue was that working directory is not passed down to the composite action.

The default working directory is not passed to the composite action.
defaults:
  run:
    working-directory: ./backend

Kudos to Benjamin W. for putting me on the right path.
I solved this by passing the working directory as an input to the composite action and running npm ci on that path.
## Composite action
...
- name: Install dependencies
  shell: bash
  working-directory: ${{ inputs.working-directory }}
  run: npm ci

